# Accessing Web Application deployed on local server through Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to access web application deployed on the local server for testing purposes. When i enter the path and execute it. it displays me

> **Failed to Construct 'URL': Invalid Base URL**

Can anyone help me about it? I tried to find out a valid one but unable to find any.

Comment: Please give some more context. How should we know why the script determines that a URL might be invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou Mateo, your answer reminded me of another tool BlazeMeter that helped me to get my BaseURL.